# Putting something below a LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I would like my screen to show a scrolling list and a button below it. The button should always be visible. I tried the following, but it did does not work. The `LazyColumn` takes the entire screen. I want the `Button` to take it's space at the bottom, and then the `LazyColumn` has the rest of the screen.

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(50) { i ->
            Text("Row $i", Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp))
        }
    }
    Button(onClick = { println("hi") }) {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can apply the [weight](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#weight-in-row-and-column) modifier to the lazyColumn:

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        items(50) { i ->
            Text("Row $i", Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp))
        }
    }
    Button(onClick = { println("hi") }) {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

This is also explained in the [Jetpack Compose basics codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#5)

Comment: ‍♂️ I had tried `weight` on the `Button`, thinking that it needs more weight to make it show up.

Comment: You are awesome

Comment: Just what I was looking for, wonderful!

Comment: what if you want button appear only during scrolling if there are many items but still be at the bottom when there is free space? in your example button is always visible at the bottom even if there are many items

Comment: If Button is a coulmn, it does not work. If the button is multiple composables, it does not work.

Comment: Striaght up does not work if Button is a Row

Comment: Doesn't work either on a BottomSheet

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely an answer to the question, but I had an issue where `LazyColum()` took up the entire width of the screen. All credit to "Sinner of the System".

Added `.padding(8.dp)` to `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` to add some space.

```
Column (
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.White),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
    ) {
        item {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(15.dp))
                Text(text = "foo,")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
                Text(text = "bar")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]