# Column disappears LazyColumn gets scrollable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a Column beneath a LazyColumn if there is a specific condition fulfilled. This Column appears as expected when my LazyColumn has just a few items available. But when the LazyColumn gets enough items to be scrollable, the Column disappears. It also isn't at the bottom of the List, its gone (or behind the LazyColumn? What wouldn't make any sense).

Did I miss a point somewhere?

```kotlin
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        val tasks =
            viewModel.filteredTasks.value
        Log.d(TAG, "Assigned Tasks: ${tasks.size}")
        Log.d(TAG, "Active Task: ${viewModel.activeTask.value}")
        if (tasks.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text("Keine Aufträge vorhanden")
            }
        } else {
            LazyColumn {
                items(tasks.size) { index ->
                    Column {
                        ListItem(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    viewModel.taskDetailId =
                                        tasks[index].montageTaskId
                                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_task_list_to_details)
                                },
                            text = {
                                Text(text = "Auftragsnummer: ${tasks[index].montageTaskId}")
                            },
                            secondaryText = {
                                Column {
                                    Text(
                                        text = stringResource(
                                            R.string.owner_string,
                                            tasks[index].locationOwner?.companyName
                                                ?: "Empty..."
                                        )
                                    )
                                    Text(
                                        text = stringResource(
                                            R.string.adress_string,
                                            tasks[index].location.street,
                                            tasks[index].location.number
                                        ),
                                    )
                                }
                            },
                            trailing = {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Default.KeyboardArrowRight,
                                    contentDescription = "Pfeil nach rechts"
                                )
                            }
                        )
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (viewModel.hasActiveTask.value) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .clickable { navigateToActivity(viewModel.taskDetailId) }
            ) {
                Divider(
                    thickness = 1.dp
                )
                Text(text = "Aktiver Auftrag")
                Text(text = "Something Something")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414177/putting-something-below-a-lazycolumn-in-jetpack-compose) and by adding `weight(1f)` modifier to your `LazyColumn` I solved the issue.

Comment: If an other answer answers the current question, it should be marked as a duplicate. If you don't have enough reputation to vote for a duplicate, you can leave a comment so others can mark it as duplicate. An answer can be posted if the current question is significantly different, in which case you can link to the other answer and add details that are relevant only to that issue. In the current case, your answer is considered low quality.

Comment: I have never before encountered a question, which would be a duplicate, but not yet marked as such. Therefore, it completely slipped my mind that I could indeed mark it as a duplicate. Thank you for your comment, I will take care to not repeat the mistake again.